# ForEach in SwiftUI Warning Issue

Tags: swiftui

I have been using SwiftUI for a few months now an I am having difficulty with using ForEach.
I am aware that the `ForEach` protocol demands a unique identifier, but I have used `/.self` to overcome that aspect of the protocol.
Now unit testing a ForEach statement but I am getting a warning which is preventing build.

> Warning is **Result of 'ForEach' initializer is
>   unused**

```
import SwiftUI

struct GetdOrderView: View {

@State private var myFamily = ["Ufuoma","Efe","David","Vicky","Beth"]


    //The use of ForEach
    func myForachOne() {

        ForEach((0 ... myFamily.count), id: \.self) {member in

            VStack {
            Text("\(member)")
        }

        }
    }


    var body: some View {

    Text("Hello world")


    }        

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> func myForachOne() {

Use

```
func myForachOne() -> some View {
```

Answer (score 1):

**//Use This**

```
import SwiftUI

    struct GetdOrderView: View {

    @State private var myFamily = ["Ufuoma","Efe","David","Vicky","Beth"]


        //The use of ForEach
        func myForachOne() -> some View {

            ForEach((0 ... myFamily.count), id: \.self) {member in

                VStack {
                Text("\(member)")
            }

            }
        }


        var body: some View {

        Text("Hello world")


        }        

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and it worked a treat. If you do not mind, can explain why it has to be formatted this way? Kind Regards

Comment: it's swiftUI Structure that's why can you please accept the answer